# "ENOENT: no such file or directory..." in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I really don't know why I get this errormessage if I want to start the emberjs server.

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
>   'D:\EmberJS\super-rentals\tmp\source_map_concat-input_base_path-Sd8yH8aX.tmp\0\vendor\ember-components\vendor\ic-styled\main.js'

I didn't do anything.
I edit my app and it still works.
After one more edit my app doesn't work anymore.

I searched in github for this issue and in google but I can't find any solutions. Now I am here and I hope somebody can help me with this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: "I didn't do anything." You did, you edited something and it broke, without knowing what it is you are editing and how there is no way for anyone to help you with it. Odds are your edits are causing an invalid syntax or importing something that doesn't exist. Without seeing your repo all we have to go on is guesses.

Comment: I change the edit so there isn't any syntax errors. I see that the problem caused by a node modul: broccoli-caching-writer

Comment: I've ran into trouble too imo close server and restart it helped.

Comment: I closed the cmd and run ember s. My problem is still there...

Comment: What version of Ember CLI are your running locally and globally?